# Transmission client can't access mounted NFS share

Tags: permissions, nfs, transmission

I set up transmission-daemon on my Scientific Linux 6.3 machine to download files to a mounted NFS share (mounted during boot via /etc/fstab). The directory that the NFS share is mounted to was chown'ed to the transmission-daemon user and group.

In the Transmission web interface, I add a test .torrent file, and got a permission denied error when Transmission tries to access the destination download directory (i.e the mounted NFS share).

However, a regular user on the SL 6.3 system can read and write to that share fine.

What should I do to resolve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post share configuration, fstab entry, `ls -la <dir>` for Downloads directory and its parent and userids for the users that transmission is running as as well as userids for the users able to access the files via NFS mount.

Answer (score 2):

For NFS v3, user id and group id have to match between both the server and the client. In this example, the user on the NFS server who has read/write permissions to the directory has uid=1000 and gid=1000. You can find what yours are with `id hpy`. Then, modify your `/etc/exports`:

`/export/media 10.1.1.0/24(rw,all_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000)`

Now, `all_squash` maps  `anonuid` and `anongid` to the anonymous user which has the effect of giving the client the same permissions as `hpy` does on the NFS server. Mount the NFS share like you normally would and you're set. This is a quick and dirty fix, but effective; the proper solution would include LDAP or some other directory services to propagate permissions to all clients correctly.